# Loop not performing as it should be

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to loop a custom post type but for some strange reason its displaying the word archieves even though this is comming from my own page template called staff.php. I have checked and the page is pointing to staff.

U can see the site here what is hapening

http://kvalixhu.digitalthinkersni.co.uk/staff/

**Edit to include full template**

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name: Staff
*/

get_header(); ?>
<div class="full-width page-header">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <h1>Munkatársaink</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row  show-for-medium-up">
    <div class="column breadcrumb">
          <?php
        if (function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb')) {
        //echo __('Home',TD) . ' > ';            
        yoast_breadcrumb('<span id="breadcrumbs">', '</span>');
        }
        ?> 
    </div>
</div>
<?php 
    $loop = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' =>  'staff',
        'posts_per_page'    =>  -1
    ));
?>
<div id="contentWrap" class="group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column small-12 blog">
            <div class="staff-content">
            <?php if($loop->have_posts()) : ?>
            <?php echo 'do i get their ';?>
                <?php while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="single-staff">
                        <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(array("class" => "mk-staff-img")); ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <h3 class="staff-name"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                        <?php $position = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), '' ); ?>
                        <h4 class="staff-position"><?php echo $position['mk_staff_info'][0]; ?></h4>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile;  else :?>



            <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>   
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Please share your full template...

Comment: Also important to note...`post_per_page` should be `posts_per_page`

Comment: @rnevius added the full template

Comment: @rnevius any ideas i made the change and its not working for some reason the page is going to archives even thoguh i have set my page template to go to staff.php

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer here for anyone else looking it was due to my page template having the same name as my page slug so i changed my page template to staff members as describe here in wordpress stack

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/34422/page-is-defaulting-to-archive-page-and-not-designated-template

Comment: I was answering my own question so please remove the markdowns this is a stalkier annoying me